# How to install GimpShop on Ubuntu 14.04 from Sourcefourge

Tags: repository, gimp

I read this article on a replacement app for PhotoShop on Ubuntu and I followed the link which brought me to [soureforge to download GimpShop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpshop.mirror/?source=typ_redirect).

I downloaded the **gimpshop-2.2.11.tar.bz2** file but how to I install the GimpSHop now!  Is there a special method to install apps from sourcefourge.

I've installed apps with the **apt-get install**  command  and **.deb** dowloads before but am not familiar how sourceforge.  Also I found a .deb downlaod available from [uptodown.com](http://gimpshop.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu) but am not sure if this is a reliable source.

Comment: Why don't you just install the standard GIMP with: `sudo apt-get install gimp`?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, I don't like the Gimp interface.  I've been using PhotoShop for years and want something more similar to it.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda perhaps you are right.  I will try out Gimp for a while first and try something like [this](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-make-the-gimp-work-more-like-photoshop-1551318983)

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question though: Gimpshop is/was a hacked version of GIMP (fork) designed to make it easier for Photoshop users to migrate to GIMP.

I also recommend that you give native GIMP a shot before trying to install Gimpshop, especially since development of the latter has been on hold for quite a while.

But, if you really want to try it (the following also applies to most downloaded tar files/builds):

```
tar -xzf gimpshop-2.2.11.tar.bz2 
cd gimpshop-2.2.11
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

If you receive a permissions error at any point (apart from general `sudo` prompts):

```
chown $USER -R ~/.gimpshop-2.2.11
```

(for example).

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong archive. Extract the archive and test only one file, eg

```
% file LICENSE.bin 
LICENSE.bin: MacBinary III data with surprising version number
```

The Download area doesn't contains a download link for a Linux version.

---

The linked deb file in your question does not look reassuring.

---

Install the latest Gimp version via

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

or a newer version via PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

and give the interface a chance.